# print pass or failed job in a parallel Jenkins code

Tags: jenkins, parallel-processing, jenkins-groovy

I'm running the following code where the idea is to run as much "TestRunner" as possible during night. I've removed some unnecessary code if some variables aren't there the for easier reading.

I want to know each job if it was successful, aborted or failed and when I'm using parallel I'm not able to see it.

How can I modify my code so i can print each job state when its done? adding a variable is being wiped out to the last element in the for loop.

Thanks a lot

```
    def numberOfRuns =  0
    def availableExecutors = 5

    def parallelRuns = [:]

// building executers for later use in parallel
    for (int i = 0; i < availableExecutors; i++) {
        parallelRuns[i] = {
            waitUntil {
                build job: 'TestRunner', parameters: [
                    string(name: 'randomBit', value: "${randomBit}"),
                ], propagate: false

                numberOfRuns++

                def now = new Date()
                return (now > workDayMorning)
            }
        }

    }
// Parallel stage - running al executers
    parallel parallelRuns
```

I've tried to enter a variable to track job process, i tried to use the parallelRuns as object but didnt manage to get the result of each test passed or not.

Comment: In each parallel branch, you are running the same job multiple times. So you want to collect the result of each run for each parallel branch? It would be helpful if you'd add a possible output.

Answer (score 0):

A solution i've found is:

```
  def Job = build job: 'TestRunner', parameters: [
     string(name: 'randomBit', value: ${randomBit}")
     ], propagate: false
     echo "Runner: ${Job.getDisplayName()} has ${Job.getResult()} 
     with duration: ${Job.getDuration()}"
```

This prints data of the job.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).